# How to use Adaptive UI for all Grid in XAML Windows 10?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

I am migrating my Windows Phone 8 App to Windows 10 and I came across new term Adaptive UI and found that it is very useful.But when I apply Adaptive UI for each Grid, only the first Grid's UI changes based on screen size, not others.I added the following code to achieve that. Please suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource AppBackGroundColor}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="517" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="LoginImage.Height" Value="60"/>
                        <Setter Target="LoginImage.Width" Value="60"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="LoginImage.Height" Value="90"/>
                        <Setter Target="LoginImage.Width" Value="80"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="/Images/login.png"
               Grid.Column="0"
               x:Name="LoginImage"
               />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualState>
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="Headertxt1.FontSize" Value="25"/>
                            <Setter Target="Headertxt2.FontSize" Value="20"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                    <VisualState>
                        <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                        </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="Headertxt1.FontSize" Value="30"/>
                            <Setter Target="Headertxt2.FontSize" Value="23"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Login"
                       Name="Headertxt1"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource AppFontColor}"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       FontWeight="Bold" />

            <TextBlock 
                       Name="Headertxt2"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource AppFontColor}"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,25,0,0">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="EmailTxtBox.Height" Value="30"/>
                        <Setter Target="PwdBox.Height" Value="30"/>
                        <Setter Target="LoginButton.FontSize" Value="25"/>
                        <Setter Target="ForgotPwdButton.FontSize" Value="20"/>

                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="EmailTxtBox.Height" Value="50"/>
                        <Setter Target="PwdBox.Height" Value="50"/>
                        <Setter Target="LoginButton.FontSize" Value="38"/>
                        <Setter Target="ForgotPwdButton.FontSize" Value="24"/>

                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox 
                 Style="{StaticResource MediumSizeTextBoxStyle}"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Name="EmailTxtBox"
                 Height="50"
                 InputScope="EmailSmtpAddress"                                                                                                 
                 Margin="12,0,12,10"/>



        <PasswordBox Name="PwdBox"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     Style="{StaticResource MediumSizePwdBoxStyle}"
                     Margin="12,10,12,4"
                     Height="50"/>


        <Button Content="Login"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Margin="12,20,12,0"
                x:Name="LoginButton"
                BorderThickness="0"
                Foreground="Black"
                Background="White"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <Button Content="Forgot Password"
                Grid.Row="3"
                Foreground="{StaticResource AppFontColor}"
                FontSize="24"
                Margin="0,10,0,10"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Name="ForgotPwdButton"
                BorderThickness="0"
                />
    </Grid>

    <Image x:Name="Header_logo"
           Source="/Images/rbkc_logo.png" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Visibility="Collapsed"
           Margin="0,10,0,10"
           Width="480" 
           Height="121" />

    <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0"
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                  />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Control authors or app developers add [VisualStateGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstategroup.aspx) object elements to the root element of a control template definition in XAML, using the [VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.visualstategroups.aspx) attached property. Within a **VisualStateGroup** element, each [VisualState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.aspx) represents a discrete visual state of a control. Each **VisualState** has a name that is representative of a UI state that can be changed by the user, or changed by control logic. A **VisualState** consists mainly of a [Storyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate.storyboard.aspx). This **Storyboard** targets individual dependency property values that should be applied whenever the control is in that visual state. For more info on how to write visual states in XAML, including example code, see [Storyboarded animations for visual states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj819808.aspx).

For more info, see [VisualStateManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.aspx).

Adding `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` in one control which is not the root element of the page does not work. You can add the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` to root Grid of the page. And add all of the `<VisualState>` to the `<VisualStateGroup>`.

By the way, you have a misunderstand. The first Grid's UI changes based on screen size, because the `Height` and `Width` of the `Image` are not explicitly specified, the default value of `Stretch` is Uniform. It will change the height and width to adaptive the `Grid`. So the "Adaptive UI" didn't works in your scenario.

For example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource AppBackGroundColor}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="LoginImage.Height" Value="60" />
                    <Setter Target="LoginImage.Width" Value="60" />
                    <Setter Target="Headertxt1.FontSize" Value="25" />
                    <Setter Target="Headertxt2.FontSize" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Target="EmailTxtBox.Height" Value="30" />
                    <Setter Target="PwdBox.Height" Value="30" />
                    <Setter Target="LoginButton.FontSize" Value="25" />
                    <Setter Target="ForgotPwdButton.FontSize" Value="20" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="LoginImage.Height" Value="90" />
                    <Setter Target="LoginImage.Width" Value="80" />
                    <Setter Target="Headertxt1.FontSize" Value="30" />
                    <Setter Target="Headertxt2.FontSize" Value="23" />
                    <Setter Target="EmailTxtBox.Height" Value="50" />
                    <Setter Target="PwdBox.Height" Value="50" />
                    <Setter Target="LoginButton.FontSize" Value="38" />
                    <Setter Target="ForgotPwdButton.FontSize" Value="24" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="517" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="/Images/login.png"
           Grid.Column="0"
           x:Name="LoginImage" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Center">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Login"
                   Name="Headertxt1"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource AppFontColor}"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   FontWeight="Bold" />

            <TextBlock
                   Name="Headertxt2"
                   Foreground="{StaticResource AppFontColor}"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,25,0,0">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox
             Style="{StaticResource MediumSizeTextBoxStyle}"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Name="EmailTxtBox"
             Height="50"
             InputScope="EmailSmtpAddress"
             Margin="12,0,12,10" />

        <PasswordBox Name="PwdBox"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Style="{StaticResource MediumSizePwdBoxStyle}"
                 Margin="12,10,12,4"
                 Height="50" />

        <Button Content="Login"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Margin="12,20,12,0"
            x:Name="LoginButton"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Foreground="Black"
            Background="White"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <Button Content="Forgot Password"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Foreground="{StaticResource AppFontColor}"
            FontSize="24"
            Margin="0,10,0,10"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Name="ForgotPwdButton"
            BorderThickness="0" />
    </Grid>

    <Image x:Name="Header_logo"
       Source="/Images/rbkc_logo.png"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       Visibility="Collapsed"
       Margin="0,10,0,10"
       Width="480"
       Height="121" />

    <Button x:Name="backButton" Margin="39,59,39,0"
                Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                AutomationProperties.Name="Back" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jayden. I will try this and mark your answer as Accepted. Also, can you also suggest, how to use Adaptive UI dynamically? I have some other pages where entire page UI is dynamic.

Comment: I am about to give you the same answer. If you want to go Adaptive UI completely dynamic. You should handle the SizeChanged event of the Grid / Page and react according to the new Size.

Comment: @thang2410199 Can you suggest some links to achieve dynamic Adaptive UI?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not give any link right now. As I said, you should implement your own logic for difference UI state, the way to achieve it vary from project to project.

Comment: Thanks, @thang2410199. It's fine for now. If I face any issues will add a question on SO.